# What is Annotation in Twilio Call API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, zapier

Trying to set a custom variable for inbound call in Twilio Studio and pass to Zapier. Zapier does not see custom variables, only one I see could possibly use is "Annotation" however cant find what that is or how to set.

See the reference here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call, but doesn't help with what Annotation variable is or used for.

```
$call = $twilio->calls
               ->create("+15558675310", // to
                        "+15017122661", // from
                        array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
               );

print($call->sid);
OUTPUT
{
  "account_sid": "AC3b3775dff0b80a1bc37850e08102db58",
  "annotation": null,
  "answered_by": null,
```

Annotation = "12345" or whatever user inputs

Answer (score -2):

Please view this article, this may help. You approach above will not as that key is not supported. You can also use HTTP Parameters in the HTTP Request Widget in Studio, to pass on parameters outside of Twilio.

[Passing Custom Information via Requests to Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011213347-Passing-Custom-Information-via-Requests-to-Twilio)

Comment: It looks like these are referencing passing variables into your Studio from outside Twilio. I want take a custom variable (call Id) and send it outside of Twilio when call is done.

Comment: It applies to both use cases.